# How can I fix the problem in while loop (processing) while trying to make rectangle loop

Tags: java, processing

What is wrong in this code?

```
 Boolean counter2, counter1, counter3, counter4;
```

This is the counter variables

```
switch(key) {
    case 'x': 
        counter3 = true;
        break; 
}
```

Switch key function

```
while(counter3 == true)
{
      int bullet = 355;
      rect(bullet, jump1, 10, 20); 
      bullet++;
}
```

While function **it keeps stopping on pressing "x"**

The full code

```
 int wm1 =355;

    int a=355;
    boolean counter2,counter1,counter3,counter4;
    int movement1=280,movement2=850;
      int jump1=380,jump2=380;
    int x,y,z;

    void setup(){
    background(200);
    }



    void settings(){

    size(600,600);

    }
    void draw(){
      background(0);
      fill(200);
    textSize(70);

    text("2p shooter game",10,150);
    textSize(60);
    fill(42);
    rect(250,300,120,60);
    fill(x,y,z);
    text("Play",250,350);
    textSize(20);
    fill(249,249,0);
    text("made by: mostafa mahmoud sayed",149,500);
    text("version:beta",250,560);
    x=x+1;
    y=y+2;
    z=z+3;

    if(mouseX<370&&mouseX>250&&mouseY<360&&mouseY>300&&mousePressed){
    delay(150);

     class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

      public void settings() {
        size(1200, 600);
      }
      public void draw() {
    background(200);
        fill(0,255,0);
        rect(50,500,500,50);
        rect(650,500,500,50);
            rect(50,220,500,50);
        rect(650,220,500,50);
        //  ground terrian //
        fill(255,0,0);
        rect(movement1,jump1,70,120);
        rect(movement1,jump1,70,50);
        //p1//
        fill(0,0,255);
        rect(movement2,jump2,70,120);
        rect(movement2,jump2,70,50);
        //p2//


            rect(wm1,jump1,10,40);

        rect(wm1,jump1,50,25);

        switch(key){
        case 'w' :  

        fill(0,0,0);
    jump1=100;
    break;
    case 'i':

    jump2=100;
    break;
    case 'd':

    counter1=true;
     break;   
     case 'a':

    counter1=false;
     break;  
      case 'l':

    counter2=true;
     break;  
      case 'j':

    counter2=false;
     break;   
     case 'k':

    jump2=380;
     break;  
      case 's':

    jump1=380;
     break;  
    case'x':counter3=true;
    break;

        }
   while(counter3==true){int bullet = 355;rect(bullet,jump1,10,20); bullet++;}
    if(counter1==true){
    movement1++;
    wm1++;
    }
    else if(counter1==false){movement1--;wm1--;}

    if(counter2==true){
    movement2++;
    }
    else if(counter2==false){movement2--;}



      }}



      String[] args = {"TwoFrameTest"};
      SecondApplet sa = new SecondApplet();
      PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);

    }
    }
```

Comment: What you've posted is not a [mre], but that looks like an infinite loop. The condition of the `while` loop isn't updated inside the body of the loop, so the body just gets executed again and again forever.

Comment: `while(counter3==true){int bullet = 355;rect(bullet,jump1,10,20); bullet++;}` is an infinite loop or won't run at all.

Comment: Do you mean instead of creating the object in the loop creating it in the body and use *while* to change variable

Comment: I'd suggest a couple of things to make your life easier: 1) properly format your code to make it more readable 2) learn the basics of object oriented programming before diving into trying to make a game 3) learn to properly use events such as keystrokes etc. - that handling of `key` looks very fragile.

Comment: thanks you all for your comments and i will think in other way for making multiple rectangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use massive loops within the draw method in processing because draw() gets called automatically every frame. Moreover, in your code, counter 3 never changes inside while loop so your code goes into an infinite loop.

Change the while to if and it should freeze no more.

```
if(counter3==true) {
    int bullet = 355;
    rect(bullet,jump1,10,20);
    bullet++;
}
```

Make sure you change counter 3 somewhere based on your program logic else it will always be true and the if block will always be executed